# How do I insert values into an multidimensional-array, then show them?

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm fairly new to php, and I don't know how to work with arrays very well. Here's the deal, I want to add into a multidimensional array three or more values I obtain from my database, then I want to sort them based on the timestamp (one of the values). After that, I want to show all of the sorted values. I can't seem to do this, here's the code

```
    $queryWaitingPatients = 'SELECT ArrivalTime, TargetTime, Order, Classification FROM exams WHERE (CurrentState = "Pending")';

    $results = mysql_query($queryWaitingPatients) or die(mysql_error());

    if (mysql_num_rows($results) == 0) {
        echo '<p>There\'s currently no patient on the waiting list.</p>';
        return;
    }
    while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
        extract($rows);
    //now is the part that I don't know, putting the values into an array
    }
    // I'm also not sure how to sort this according to my $TargetTime
    asort($sortedTimes);

     //the other part I don't know, showing the values,
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: **FYI:** `order` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Wrap it in backticks or use another word, `Orders` for instance.

Comment: Why don't you use a ORDER BY in your sql query? This way data comes in sorted already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's look at your code. First, you have a query that's returning a result set. I don't recommend using `mysql_fetch_array` because it's not only [deprecated](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) (use `mysqli` functions instead) but it tends to lend itself to bad code. It's hard to figure out what you're referencing when all your keys are numbers. So I recommend [mysqli_fetch_assoc](https://www.php.net/mysqli_fetch_assoc) (be sure you're fully switched to the `mysqli` functions first, like `mysql_connect` and `mysqli_query`)

Second, I really dislike using extract. We need to work with the array directly. Here's how we do this

```
$myarray = array();
while ($rows = mysqlI_fetch_assoc($results)) {
    $myarray[] = $rows;
}
echo $myarray[0]['ArrivalTime'];
```

So let's go over this. First, we're building an array of arrays. So we initialize our overall `array`. Then we want to push the rows onto this array. That's what `$myarray[]` does. Finally, the array we're pushing is associative, meaning all the keys of the row match up with the field names of your query.

Now, the sorting really needs to be done in your query. So let's tweak your query

```
$queryWaitingPatients = 'SELECT ArrivalTime, TargetTime, `Order`, Classification 
    FROM exams 
    WHERE CurrentState = "Pending"
    ORDER BY TargetTime';
```

This way, when your PHP runs, your database now churns them out in the correct order for your array. No sorting code needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was really insightful and detailed. I'm still a newbie, as I don't know many functions, which kinda makes me a little bit constrained. As for the sort, I was going to need it later on, after changing the $myarray

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = array(); 
while ($rows = mysql_fetch_array($results)) {
     array_push ($arr, $row);
}

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$queryWaitingPatients = ' SELECT ArrivalTime, TargetTime, Order, Classification, CurrentState 
                          FROM exams 
                          WHERE CurrentState = "Pending"
                          ORDER BY TargetTime ';

$results = mysql_query($queryWaitingPatients) or die(mysql_error());
    if ($results -> num_rows < 1)
    {
        echo '<p>There\'s currently no patient on the waiting list.</p>';
     }
     else
    {
     while ($rows = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
       {
         $arrivaltime = $row['ArrivalTime'];
         $targettime = $row['targettime'];
         $order = $row['Order'];
         $classification = $row['Classification'];
         echo   "Arrival: ".$arrivaltime."--Target time: ".$targettime."--Order: ".$order."--Classification: ".$classification;
        }
     }
echo "Done!";
//or you could put it in a json array and pass it to client side.
?>
```